# Monitoring process to be always running

Tags: c#, monitoring

Anybody knows how I could make a Monitor program in C# to control that an application will always be running? That I need it's a double monitor application, I will explain: I have a application Ap1 that have to control that Ap2 process it's always started, and Ap2 have to control that Ap1 process it's always started. In resume, if I kill Ap1 process the Ap2 application should start Ap1 immediatelly (and vice versa if Ap2 die).

This the code that I'm developing but didn't work, I don't know but when I kill the program monitored no started again.

```
        public void Monitor()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Monitoring {0} process...", processname);

            while (IsProcessRunning() == true)
            {
                Process[] runningNow = Process.GetProcesses();

                foreach (Process process in runningNow)
                {
                    if (process.ProcessName == processname)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Process:{0} is running actually", process.ProcessName);
                    }
                    else { /* Provide a messagebox. */ }
                }

                // Sleep till the next loop
                Thread.Sleep(intInterval);
            }



            while (IsProcessRunning() != true)
            {
                ProcessMonitor proc = new ProcessMonitor("ConsoleApplication1", 1000);//Check if is running each 1 second
                Console.WriteLine("Process:{0} is NOT running actually", processname);
                //Application folder of exe
                String applicationFolder = "C:\\App";

                //Get the executable file
                String procPath = applicationFolder + @"\Ap1.exe";

                Console.WriteLine("Running {0} process...", proc.Name);
                //Lauch process
                Process p = Process.Start(procPath);
                Console.WriteLine("Process running {0} OK", proc.Name);
                //p.WaitForExit(10000);
            }
        }
```

And the main program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessMonitor proc = new ProcessMonitor("ConsoleApplication1", 1000);//Check if is running each 1 second
        if (proc.IsProcessRunning() != true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not running.", proc.Name);

            //Application folder of exe
            String applicationFolder = "C:\\App";

            //Get the executable file
            String procPath = applicationFolder + @"\Ap1.exe";

            Console.WriteLine("Running {0} process...", proc.Name);
            //Lauch process
            Process p = Process.Start(procPath);
            Console.WriteLine("Process running {0} OK", proc.Name);
            //p.WaitForExit(10000);
        }
        else
        {
            proc.Monitor();
        }

        proc.FreezeOnScreen(); 
    }
```

Comment: Yes, we know. (to read as: OK, so far what you tried? SO is to solve specific problems, not to ask for a ready solution without some initial effort)

Comment: check Process list periodically and run the app if doesn't exists

Comment: Don't do this. This would be so inherently user hostile that it sounds like malware to me - **just create a window service instead**.  If you *really* want to do it, then you have already described the approach in your question (have each process check if the other is running and start it if its not)

Comment: I would use a windows service and I would look into service dependencies

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Justin We've had the case that a Windows service depending on a third party library just quit due to the badly coded third party library. The service needed to be always-on, so we created a monitor service, too. It's not always user hostile to do what the OP is asking :-)

Comment: @dferraro Circular dependencies?

Comment: @Thorsten Ditmar, I never said it was a good idea or not. I simply said that's the first thing I would google :)

Comment: @Adriano I have update my currect solution. It is a class that specifying the name of a program it monitos, but I don't know why when the monitorized application it's killed didn't start again.

Comment: I'd make a tour with debugger, I don't know what IsProcessRunning() is doing but code looks little bit strange (what's the meaning of that two loops?) Moreover you don't catch any exception (and there may be). Moreover...what's your minimum supported OS? Windows (from Vista, I think) offers that service for applications, not only for services (but you have to write some code, it's not "for free").

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a task in the task scheduler that launches your program at a set interval (say every half hour). I believe you can set it to not start the task if there is already an instance running. (Correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

We needed this once and simply monitored the process list periodically, checking for the name of the process. If the process wasn't present for a given amount of time, we restarted it. You can use [`Process.GetProcessesByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I already tried that bus I don't know why the program once killed not started again. I have update my code in the description.

Comment: Did you try to use `ProcessStartupInfo` with `UseShellExecute = true`?